# Weird issue with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this really basic HTML page:

```html
<textarea id='carmodeldescription' name="carmodeldescription"></textarea>

<br/>

<button id='#booboo'>button</button>
```

And this jQuery:

```
$('#booboo').click(function(e){
    e.PreventDefault;
    var texttosubmit = $('#carmodeldescription').html();
    alert(texttosubmit);
    return false;
});
```

When I type something in the `<textarea>` and click the button, it `alert()`s an empty string.

**But**, if after `e.PreventDefault;` I put this line of code:

```
$("#carmodeldescription").html('texttosubmit');
```

It works (adds 'texttosubmit' to textarea and then alerts it).

Comment: is the id unique on that page?

Comment: It's `.preventDefault()`, and you get the value of a `<textarea>` with `.val()`, not `.html()`.

Comment: Do you seriously have `id="#booboo"` in the HTML, instead of `id="booboo"`? And did you really write `e.PreventDefault;` instead of `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: @kojiro: it is some kind of spirct with a subtle difference to a scirpt, but that is quite hard to understand and even harder to explain...

Comment: @AresAvatar: It's best to not correct the code in the question. It may be actual copy/paste code that represents an issue to be corrected.

Comment: @amnot Usually I don't, but in this case, however, it wasn't part of the issue.  Disagree with your revert but I'm not going to get into a war over it so I'll just leave the OP to correcting it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using `val` rather than `html` to get the value of the textarea:

```
$('#carmodeldescription').val()
```

Also, `e.preventDefault;` does nothing without parenthesis after it: `e.preventDefault();` and @Phrogz pointed out that javascript is case sensitive and `PreventDefault` does not exist... Use `preventDefault` instead.

Comment: Uh, you might want to fix the casing on `preventDefault`.

Comment: @Phrogz, You think I should call out the id issue too? Or how preventDefault + return false is redundant-ish?

Answer (score 4):

Use `$('#carmodeldescription').val()` instead of `.html()`.

Comment: D'oh! You beat me by 11 seconds! ;)

Comment: @Prestaul On the other hand, you answered two questions at the same time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
 $("#carmodeldescription").val();
```

I think that is what you are looking for.